# Design patterns Magento 2

Tags: magento, design-patterns, magento2

Magento is a pretty complex application. And knowing as a large open source ecommerce platform. Throughout Magento 1 architecture, it commonly used [12 design patterns](http://www.coolryan.com/magento-design-patterns/) which allows developers to view and use them in real.

As you know, Magento 2 is coming soon. I want to know what patterns are approved? And give us some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best solution for you is take a look into [Magento 2 documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/) and [source code](https://github.com/magento/magento2).

Answer (score 4):

1. Composite Pattern
2. Strategy Pattern
3. Factory Method Pattern
4. Observer Pattern
5. Object Manager (which consist of 11+ Design Patterns)
6. Decorator Pattern
7. Proxy Pattern

Comment: How do you know the list?